# Storing structs in Glib Queues

Tags: c, queue, glib

I have a bug where a struct which is popped off a glib queue has lost some of it's assigned data.

the struct is as follows:

```
typedef struct src_file {
    off_t size;
    int filename;
    const char *file_path;
} src_file;
```

`new_src_file()` is defined as:

```
src_file* new_src_file(const char * src_filepath, off_t size, int filename) {
    src_file *sh_src_file = malloc(sizeof(src_file));
    sh_src_file->file_path = src_filepath;
    sh_src_file->size = size;
    sh_src_file->filename = filename;
    return sh_src_file;
}
```

This is populated by a nftw callback function which also pushes the object onto the queue

```
  src_file *sh_src_file = new_src_file(fpath, statptr->st_size, pfwt->base);
  g_queue_push_tail(sh_file_list, sh_src_file);
```

This structure contains the Gqueue that we are trying to populate with src_file structures. `sh_file_list` is the global queue that is needed to work with nftw. It is copied in `new_src_handler()`

```
typedef struct src_handler {
    GQueue* src_list;
    off_t src_size;
} src_handler;
```

```
src_handler* new_src_handler(char* src_path) {
    sh_total = 0;
    src_handler *sources = malloc(sizeof(src_handler));
    sources->src_list = g_queue_new();
    sh_file_list = g_queue_new();
    int fd_limit = 5;
    int flags = FTW_CHDIR | FTW_DEPTH | FTW_MOUNT | FTW_PHYS;
    int ret = nftw(src_path, process, fd_limit, flags);
    sources->src_size = sh_total;
    sources->src_list = g_queue_copy(sh_file_list);
    g_queue_free(sh_file_list);
    return sources;
}
```

Looking at the variables via the debugger suggests that all the information within the structure is being stored.

This queue is used by another function to process the files stored within it. I am popping the head off the queue and storing it in a temporary src_file structure, the file_path is passed to another function but it is coming off the queue as "".

```
int process(...) {
    src_file *src = g_queue_pop_head(copy_job->source_files->src_list);

    printf("%.2f\n", src->size);
    printf("%d\n", src->filename);
    printf("%s\n", src->file_path);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Scanning Source: /home/user/Downloads/
Total entries: 2
Total Size 128.00
Filename: 23
File Path:
```

I don't understand what is going on with the file_path variable, why has that not properly been popped off the queue? The debugger shows that all data was present when it was pushed onto the queue. Am I doing something wrong or is there some data being over written in memory?

[image: Debugger output]

[image: debugger output]

First image is the output from the debugger just as the `sh_src_file` is pushed onto the queue

Second is when it is popped off the queue. values 12 and 23 carry over but the file_path is "" where it should be a path.

Added some more debugging messages issue appears to be with the `g_queue_copy()` function, as seen in `new_src_handler()` Something strange is happening after nftw has finished it's callback function.

```
int process(const char *fpath, const struct stat *statptr, int flags, struct FTW *pfwt) {
    if(flags == FTW_F) {
        if(strcmp(fpath + pfwt->base, ".DS_Store") != 0) {
            src_file *sh_src_file = new_src_file(fpath, statptr->st_size, pfwt->base);
            g_queue_push_head(sh_file_list, sh_src_file);
            src_file *temp = g_queue_peek_head(sh_file_list);
            printf("Pushed %s onto the queue\n", temp->file_path);
            sh_total += sh_src_file->size;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output confirms that these have been pushed onto the queue:

```
Pushed /home/howard/Downloads/test.txt onto the queue
Pushed /home/howard/Downloads/testtwo.txt onto the queue
```

However:

```
src_handler* new_src_handler(char* src_path) {
    sh_total = 0;
    src_handler *sources = malloc(sizeof(src_handler));
    sources->src_list = g_queue_new();
    sh_file_list = g_queue_new();
    int fd_limit = 5;
    int flags = FTW_CHDIR | FTW_DEPTH | FTW_MOUNT | FTW_PHYS;
    
    int ret = nftw(src_path, process, fd_limit, flags);
    //re-entry after process()
    
    sources->src_size = sh_total;
    
    //copy global sh_file_list populated by process() to our structure
    sources->src_list = g_queue_copy(sh_file_list); 
    
    //debugging
    src_file *_test = g_queue_peek_head(sources->src_list);
    src_file *_gtest = g_queue_peek_head(sh_file_list);
    
    printf("Peeking sh_file_list (global pre-copy) head: %s\n", _gtest->file_path);
    printf("Peeking src_list head: %s\n", _test->file_path);
    
    g_queue_clear(sh_file_list);
    return sources;
}
```

Output what was on the queue in process() is not the same as what is peeked in the new_src_handler():

```
Peeking sh_file_list (global pre-copy) head: /home/howard/Downloads
Peeking src_list head: /home/howard/Downloads
```

Comment: Without you providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it’s hard to tell for sure. In particular, your question is missing the code from `new_src_file()`. My guess would be that `src->file_path` is being set to some shared location which is overwritten by a subsequent call to `new_src_file()`, rather than a new string allocation for each `src_file` instance.

Comment: I have added the `new_src_file()` function code in the edit. Apologies.

Comment: https://github.com/ditServices/hash_copy_tool full code can be found here

Comment: Try changing `sh_src_file->file_path = src_filepath;` to `sh_src_file->file_path = g_strdup (src_filepath);` and adding a corresponding `g_free()` for the `file_path` member when you free the queue entries.

Comment: this didn't work it's still coming off the queue as ""

Comment: I have added some screenshots from the debugger to illustrate the issue

Comment: Did you actually try using `g_strdup()`? From your git repository it looks like you have used `sh_src_file->file_path = malloc(sizeof(src_filepath)); sh_src_file->file_path = src_filepath;`, which is not the same. The first line of code leaks the memory from `malloc()` and its value is overwritten by `src_filepath` from the second line. `src_filepath` will point to an internal buffer from `nftw()` which it overwrites with a new path every time it calls your callback function.

Comment: Yes i just haven't pushed that to the repo, it's updated now.

Comment: My next suggestion would be to use your debugger to look at the pointer values of the `src_file` objects on each `nftw()` iteration, and see if they are changing (new allocations) or all pointing to the same allocation with each iteration. Same for the `src_handler` objects. This feels like an issue where two pointers are pointing to the same heap allocation, and the data within that allocation is changed over time.

Comment: Seems to be working now, I noticed an error in the `new_src_file()` what is the best way to free the memory allocated with `g_strdup()` Do i need to `g_queue_foreach()` and create a function to free each object within the queue or will `g_queue_free()` handle all that?

Comment: Glad you got it working. Look at [`g_queue_clear_full()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Double-ended-Queues.html#g-queue-clear-full) and [`g_queue_free_full()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Double-ended-Queues.html#g-queue-free-full). `g_queue_free()` by itself can’t handle freeing the data allocated inside your queue elements because it has no idea how to free them — all `GQueue` knows is an opaque pointer for each queue element.

Comment: I'm seeing `==20837==    by 0x48C589D: g_queue_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.6600.7)
` and `==20837==    by 0x4882CBC: g_array_append_vals (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.6600.7)
` In my valgrind output, it's tracing these calls back to the parent functions, is this anything to worry about?

Comment: Looks like you’re leaking a `GQueue` instance (from a quick look, you’re assigning twice to `sources->src_list` in `new_src_handler()`), and also leaking the array segment from `copy_job->hashed_file_paths` (pass `TRUE` as the second argument to `g_array_free()`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230068/discussion-between-hdcdigi-and-philip-withnall).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the new_src_handler with `g_strdup` solved the issue.